# Breeding turtles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a little ocean area for some turtles and 2 of the 4 turtles are not laying their eggs, I spawned them in and they are still in the same place and haven’t be moved, does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to breed turtles, you'll have to do so manually. Spawning in Turtles does not give them the desire to breed automatically.

> If two turtles are fed with seagrass, they will enter love mode. One of the turtles will then have an egg in its inventory, and will begin making its way back to its home beach.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Turtle#Breeding)

Additionally, like when you breed most animals, only one offspring is born. In this situation, there is a "mother" and a "father" (though there is no indicator of which is which). In regards to Turtles, one will lay the eggs, and the other will return to swimming around, as it is the "father" in that particular reaction.

EDIT: after playing around with turtle breeding for a while, I have noticed some strange behaviours.

1. After breeding, the "mother" turtle will mull around for a while, finding a place to lay her eggs. Depending on how many other eggs are in the same spot, this can take some time. They will alternate between digging in the sand and moving about, and this can take as long as 3 minutes, by my observation.
2. After laying their eggs, normally turtles (unlike all other animals) don't have a "cooldown" before entering "love mode" again. I have personally experienced a few times where after laying eggs, a turtle will *not* go back into love mode, but if there is another turtle nearby in "love mode", it will act as if it *is* already in "love mode", and automatically breed with that turtle.

I think, potentially, you are experiencing the first issue, where the turtle does not seem to be able to locate a valid location to lay its eggs.

Comment: I bred them and all but one has laid its eggs and this wasn’t the first time they were bred they have been bred 2 times before this and everything was fine

Comment: The mother turtle gets a bigger belly, that's how you can differentiate them.