# My turtles just won’t lay their eggs

Tags: minecraft-commands

So, I spawned sea turtles on a beach. I bred them. The pregnant one just jumped into the ocean, not even going to the original beach, and started to turn in circles everywhere. I did not breed them on the same beach as the one that they were spawned on, but I had a clear path. Would holding the female captive work? This is in Minecraft P.E. by the way.

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/348596/73976)

Comment: Try placing more sand blocks in the water next to the beach. Turtles sometimes go into the water despite wanting to go to the beach and then have a hard time getting back on land.

Comment: Good idea. I let my turtle go in the water, and she won’t come out!

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition of Minecraft is being played.